# Regex modification in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am using the following regex pattern to identify the abbreviations.

```
mytext = "This is AVGs and (NMN) and most importantly GFD"
mytext= re.sub(r"\b[A-Z\.]{2,}s?\b", "_ABB", mytext)
print(mytext)
```

I get the output as follows.

```
This is _ABB and (_ABB) and most importantly _ABB
```

However, I want to get the output as;

```
This is AVGs_ABB and (NMN_ABB) and most importantly GFD_ABB
```

Please let me know where I am making it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a capture group to capture the pattern between word boundaries which you are matching, and then use it in the replacement.  The first capture group will be made available as `\\1`.

```
mytext = "This is AVGs and (NMN) and most importantly GFD"
mytext= re.sub(r"\b([A-Z\.]{2,}s?)\b", "\\1_ABB", mytext)
print(mytext)
```

### Demo of code snippet

Comment: Sure, I will :)

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this, as I get an error for my real dataset as `error: invalid group reference 1`

Comment: You have non matching text it seems.  What do you want to happen in this case?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think it is not a problem with the regex because this `mytext= re.sub(r"\b[A-Z\.]{2,}s?\b", "", mytext)` works fine. However with `\\1_ABB` the error occurs. Please let me know if there is an alternative to fix this :)

Comment: You are missing my point.  The error you are getting is because you ran `re.sub` on text which did _not_ have a matching first group.  Can you share that text with us?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes sure, my text is `"MOOCs TESting 'Chinese' Word's Segmentation."`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh! I am just wondering why it gives me error in my python spyder program. Anyway, thanks. I will check my code again

Comment: Try Wiktor's answer, which might work for you right away.

Answer (score 0):

Use exclusion while substitution as follows:

```
import re 
mytext = "This is AVGs and (NMN) and most importantly GFD"
mytext= re.sub(r"([A-Z]{2,})", "\\1_ABB", mytext)
print(mytext)
```

**output:**

`This is AVGs_ABB and (NMN_ABB) and most importantly GFD_ABB`

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
In [1]: str = "This is AVGs and (NMN) and most importantly GFD"
In [2]: regex = "[A-Z]{2,}"
In [3]: import re
In [4]: result = re.sub(regex, "_ABB", str)
In [5]: result
Out[5]: 'This is _ABBs and (_ABB) and most importantly _ABB'
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use any capturing groups here because you want to replace with the whole match, which is itself Group 0. Just use `\g<0>` in the replacement pattern, see [Python `re` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

> The backreference `\g<0>` substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.

See an [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/9GwM73):

```
import re
mytext = "This is AVGs and (NMN) and most importantly GFD"
mytext= re.sub(r"\b[A-Z.]{2,}s?\b", r"\g<0>_ABB", mytext)
print(mytext)
# => This is AVGs_ABB and (NMN_ABB) and most importantly GFD_ABB
```

The replacement is now `r"\g<0>_ABB"` and it replaces each non-overlapping match with the match found and appends `_ABB` to it.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PKRtP5/1).

Note also, that inside a character class, `.` is parsed as a regular `.` symbol, not as a "wildcard" matching any char but line break chars.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer :)